# Как добавить данные из input в функцию?

Tags: javascript, translit

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть функция которая позволяет делать транслитерацию русского языка на английский.

Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки отправить форму, данные из формы добавлялись в функцию в качестве аргумента и выводился результат с помощью alert??

```
function translit (word) {
    let answer = '';
    let converter = {
        'а': 'a',    'б': 'b',    'в': 'v',    'г': 'g',    'д': 'd',
        'е': 'e',    'ё': 'e',    'ж': 'zh',   'з': 'z',    'и': 'i',
        'й': 'y',    'к': 'k',    'л': 'l',    'м': 'm',    'н': 'n',
        'о': 'o',    'п': 'p',    'р': 'r',    'с': 's',    'т': 't',
        'у': 'u',    'ф': 'f',    'х': 'h',    'ц': 'c',    'ч': 'ch',
        'ш': 'sh',   'щ': 'sch',  'ь': '',     'ы': 'y',    'ъ': '',
        'э': 'e',    'ю': 'yu',   'я': 'ya',
 
        'А': 'A',    'Б': 'B',    'В': 'V',    'Г': 'G',    'Д': 'D',
        'Е': 'E',    'Ё': 'E',    'Ж': 'Zh',   'З': 'Z',    'И': 'I',
        'Й': 'Y',    'К': 'K',    'Л': 'L',    'М': 'M',    'Н': 'N',
        'О': 'O',    'П': 'P',    'Р': 'R',    'С': 'S',    'Т': 'T',
        'У': 'U',    'Ф': 'F',    'Х': 'H',    'Ц': 'C',    'Ч': 'Ch',
        'Ш': 'Sh',   'Щ': 'Sch',  'Ь': '',     'Ы': 'Y',    'Ъ': '',
        'Э': 'E',    'Ю': 'Yu',   'Я': 'Ya'
    };
 
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; ++i ) {
        if (converter[word[i]] == undefined){
            answer += word[i];
        } else {
            answer += converter[word[i]];
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: для этого форма не нужна. достаточно просто инпута и кнопки.... а в некоторых случаях и просто инпута

Comment: Используйте `querySelector` для работы с инпутом и  `addEventListener` для добавления события

Answer (score 0):

как вам  написали выше в комментах:

```js
let inp = document.querySelector('.inp');
let translated = document.querySelector('.translated');

inp.addEventListener('change', (e) => translit(e.target.value))
function translit (word) {
let answer = '';
let converter = {
    'а': 'a',    'б': 'b',    'в': 'v',    'г': 'g',    'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e',    'ё': 'e',    'ж': 'zh',   'з': 'z',    'и': 'i',
    'й': 'y',    'к': 'k',    'л': 'l',    'м': 'm',    'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o',    'п': 'p',    'р': 'r',    'с': 's',    'т': 't',
    'у': 'u',    'ф': 'f',    'х': 'h',    'ц': 'c',    'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh',   'щ': 'sch',  'ь': '',     'ы': 'y',    'ъ': '',
    'э': 'e',    'ю': 'yu',   'я': 'ya',
 
    'А': 'A',    'Б': 'B',    'В': 'V',    'Г': 'G',    'Д': 'D',
    'Е': 'E',    'Ё': 'E',    'Ж': 'Zh',   'З': 'Z',    'И': 'I',
    'Й': 'Y',    'К': 'K',    'Л': 'L',    'М': 'M',    'Н': 'N',
    'О': 'O',    'П': 'P',    'Р': 'R',    'С': 'S',    'Т': 'T',
    'У': 'U',    'Ф': 'F',    'Х': 'H',    'Ц': 'C',    'Ч': 'Ch',
    'Ш': 'Sh',   'Щ': 'Sch',  'Ь': '',     'Ы': 'Y',    'Ъ': '',
    'Э': 'E',    'Ю': 'Yu',   'Я': 'Ya'
};
 
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; ++i ) {
    if (converter[word[i]] == undefined){
        answer += word[i];
    } else {
        answer += converter[word[i]];
    }
}
translated.innerText = answer ;//если хотите выводить итоговую строку через алерт, то замените этот код на alert(answer)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class = 'inp'>
<div class="translated"></div>
```